# Why is autopickup on even though I disabled it in nethackrc?

Tags: nethack

I created an .nethackrc to make nethack fitting my needs with the following line :

```
OPTIONS=autodig,!autopickup
```

But even if I disabled autopickup, it is still activated in game and it is very annoying...

I'm running nethack 3.4.3

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- Is your config file in the [correct location](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Option)?  You can test that by setting some easily visible option like `name` and starting a new game to see if it has effect.
- Do you have a `NETHACKOPTIONS` environment variable that might be overriding your options?
- Did you toggle autopickup from the Options menu or [press `@` by accident](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Autopickup) while playing?

Comment: My nethack rc is well loaded (I activate color for example and it work, and setted up a custom name for my dog), but this option still activated. `echo $NETHACKOPTIONS` returns nothing. And I think I haven't typed `@` (Alt Gr O is a big accident I think...).

Comment: @MARTINDamien You've accepted this answer, but also added a comment suggesting none of its suggestions are correct. Is your comment out of date?

Answer (score 7):

Changing the autopickup setting in the rc file only affects new games you start after the change. It does not affect games you load from a previous save file.

The reason for this is that you'll often want to change the autopickup settings during the course of a game without affecting future games. So that setting is saved as part of the save file, so that if you change the setting in-game, it will be remembered if you save the game and later load it again. As a consequence changing the rc file won't have any effect on already saved games.